# Calculus: simpler way of showing that derivative is negative?

Tags: calculus, inequality, derivatives

I want to show that

$\frac{1-(1-\beta)^N}{\beta}$

is strictly decreasing in $\beta$ for $\beta \in (0,1)$ and $N \geq 2$.

My approach so far is as follows: I take the derivative with respect to $\beta$, which gives me

$\frac{d}{d\beta}\left(\frac{1-(1-\beta)^N}{\beta}\right) \propto N(1-\beta)^{N-1}\beta - [1-(1-\beta)^N]$.

I want to show that this is negative for $N \geq 2$. So I now take the derivative with respect to $N$, which has the same sign as

$\beta + [1+\beta(N-1)]\log(1-\beta)$, which in turn is strictly negative because it holds that $\log(1-\beta) \leq -\beta$.

Hence it suffices to check that $\frac{d}{d\beta}\left(\frac{1-(1-\beta)^N}{\beta}\right)$ is negative for $N = 2$, i.e., that

$2(1-\beta)\beta - [1-(1-\beta)^2] < 0$, which is easy to verify.

But now my question is: is there any simpler, more direct way? I'd like to avoid this somewhat tedious proof, if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to use
\begin{align*}
1-\left(  1-\beta\right)  ^{N}  & =\left(  1-\left(  1-\beta\right)  \right)
\left[
%TCIMACRO{\dsum \limits_{k=0}^{N-1}}%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1}}
%EndExpansion
\left(  1-\beta\right)  ^{k}\right]  \\
& =\beta%
%TCIMACRO{\dsum \limits_{k=0}^{N-1}}%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1}}
%EndExpansion
\left(  1-\beta\right)  ^{k}%
\end{align*}
So
$$
\frac{1-\left(  1-\beta\right)  ^{N}}{\beta}=%
%TCIMACRO{\dsum \limits_{k=0}^{N-1}}%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1}}
%EndExpansion
\left(  1-\beta\right)  ^{k}\text{ }%
$$
is decreasing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's basically exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h(x) = f(x) g(x)$ with $f,g$ be strictly decreasing and $f(x),g(x) >0$ then :
$$h'(x) = f'(x) g(x) + f(x) g'(x) = - \left(\lvert f'(x)\rvert g(x) + \lvert g'(x)\rvert f(x)\right) < 0$$
Hence $h$ is strictly decreasing.

Now let $f(\beta) = 1-(1-\beta)^N$ and $g(\beta) = \dfrac{1}{\beta}$ with $\beta \in (0,1)$, $N\geq 2$. We clearly have $f(\beta),g(\beta)> 0$ and$f'(\beta),g'(\beta) < 0$.

Thus $\dfrac{1-(1-\beta)^N}{\beta}$ is strictly decreasing.

Comment: Thanks for your input! That's a nice trick to remember.